# change Bar Chart's ColorAttr in Bokeh 0.11

Tags: bokeh, palette

*Note from maintainers: This question as originally posed concerns the obsoleted and removed `bokeh.charts` API. See [Handling Categorical Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) for information on Bar cahrts in modern Bokeh*

---

The default color palette used in Bokeh's Bar chart's ColorAttr only has six elements and that poses obvious limitation.  Supposedly one can change the Colorattr helper function with same a different palette like Spectral10

But I have a hard time figuring how to apply that to an actual chart.  Does anyone have an example of how to do assign a new palette like Spectral10 to the ColorAttr function and then assign the new ColorAttr to a Bar char?

Thanks!
SH

Answer (score 0):

It is actually straightforward, although it is certainly not easy to find in the documentation. You assign the palette with an argument in the Bar chart call:

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral10

p=Bar( ... ,palette=Spectral10)
```

If it may be of any use, here is also a code snippet (adapted from other contributors) that I use to generate palettes with an arbitrary number of colors:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

colormap =cm.get_cmap("jet")
different_colors=15
color_mapping=colormap(np.linspace(0,1,different_colors),1,True)
bokeh_palette=["#%02x%02x%02x" % (r, g, b) for r, g, b in color_mapping[:,0:3]]
```